# Почему не работает символ перевода строки?

Tags: c

Почему не производится перевода строки а выводится `/n`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("Введите первую букву животного: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    switch (c)
    {
     case ('А'):
     case ('а'):
        printf("Антилопа/n"); break;
     case ('Б'):
     case ('б'):
        printf("Барсук/n"); break;
     default:
        printf("Не знаю таких!/n");
    }
 getchar();
}
```

Выводится как:

[image: Антилопа/n]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что спецсимволы вводятся с обратной косой чертой. Конкретно в вашем случае должно быть "\n", а не "/n".